# Title not rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

This seems like it should be fairly easy, but I can't get the syntax down.

When I request /Years/1956, I want the title to render as 1956; for /Years/1957, I want to see 1957, etc.

Years.cshtml

```
@page "{Year:min(1956):max(2022)?}"
@model Alpha.Pages.YearsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "@Year";
}
```

Years.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Alpha.Pages {
    public class YearsModel : PageModel {
        public IActionResult OnGet(string Year) {
            if (@Year is null)
                return new RedirectToPageResult("Index");
            else
                return new PageResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion like below:

1. Inside the Razor PageModel class, set the public property `Year`.

   ```
     public class YearsModel : PageModel
       {
           public string Year { get; set; }
           public IActionResult OnGet(string Year)
           {
               if (@Year is null)
                   return new RedirectToPageResult("Index");
               else              
                   this.Year = Year;
               return new PageResult();
           }
       }
   ```
2. Then inside the Razor HTML Page, the public property `Year` is accessed from the Razor PageModel class and displayed.

```
  @page "{Year:min(1956):max(2022)?}"
  @model Alpha.Pages.YearsModel
  
  @{
      ViewData["Title"] = @Model.Year;
  }
```

3.result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem and got me going again. Much appreciated!